# If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for $x \in S$ and $\int_S f=\int_S g$, then $f$ and $g$ agree except on a set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $f,g: S\to \mathbb{R}$. If we assume $f$ and $g$ are integrable over $S$, then I'm trying to show:

> If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for $x \in S$ and $\int_S f=\int_S g$, then $f$ and $g$ agree except on a set of measure zero.

(Note that this is Riemann integration, and the concept of measurable function and measurable set has never been introduced. The only concept from measure theory that has been introduced in the text is measure zero and all we can use is the fact that Riemann integration over a set of measure zero is 0)

I have seen several proofs of this on ME, but they seem to use a lot of epsilons and 1/n tricks which I'm not sure is necessary. So here is what I have and I would like to know if anything is missing anything.

Since $f\leq g$, then $g-f\geq 0$. Consider the set $A=\{x | g(x)-f(x)\gt 0\}$. In A complement, the integral of f and g are equal. By monotonicity, $\int_S f\leq \int_S g$ so
$$\int_S f\,=\int_{S-A}f\,+\int_{A}f\,\,\leq\int_{S-A}g\,+\int_{A}g\,=\int_S g\,$$. Now by hypothesis, we are given that these integrals are equal. Also $f=g$ in S-A. It is only in A where $g>f$. But since we have equality, the set A must have measure zero.

Is this good enough? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't give an argument why $\int_A f = \int_A g$ implies that $A$ has measure zero when $f<g$ on $A$.

Comment: You've come up with all the right ideas, the main issue is that your statement of them is a bit unclear. If you include the argumentation for what Christoph pointed out (which isn't complicated by any stretch, the groundwork is already laid out here) then I'd say your proof is satisfactory, but I think it could be written a bit more directly.

Comment: @StephenDonovan ok thank you